# Using prisma, get the max id row for the included related table for checking if value matches

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have the below code for prisma to get voters that have been assigned to users. It works with the filter values except for pledges. For pledges, it needs to check if the voter's pledges table MAX row for the pledgeType="BlockAgent" has pledgeStatus value of filter.pledge. If it does not match, it should not be included in the result set.

```
if(filter) {
      if(filter.atoll) {
        where.voter = { atoll: { contains: filter.atoll, mode: 'insensitive' } }
      }

      if(filter.island) {
        where.voter = { island: { contains: filter.island, mode: 'insensitive' } }
      }

      if(filter.currentIsland) {
        where.voter = { currentIsland: { contains: filter.currentIsland, mode: 'insensitive' } }
      }

      if(filter.politicalParty) {
        where.voter = { politicalParty: { contains: filter.politicalParty, mode: 'insensitive' } }
      }

      if(filter.belongsToBlock) {
        const input = filter.belongsToBlock.trim().toLowerCase()

        where.voter = {
          belongsToBlock: {
            name: {
              equals: input,
              mode: 'insensitive',
            }
          }
        }

      }

      if(filter.pledge) {

        const maxIdSubquery = await this.prisma.$queryRaw<number>`
          SELECT MAX("id")
          FROM "VoterPledge" AS "vp"
          JOIN "Voter" AS "v" ON "v"."id" = "vp"."voterId"
          JOIN "userVoterAssignment" AS "uva" ON "v"."id" = "uva"."voterId"
          WHERE "uva"."id" = "userVoterAssignment"."id"
          AND "vp"."pledgeType" = 'BlockAgent'
        `;

        where.voter = {
          pledges: {
            some: {
              id: maxIdSubquery[0].max,
              pledgeStatus: {
                equals: filter.pledge,
                mode: 'insensitive',
              },
            },
          },
        };

      }
    }
```

```
const getAssigned = await this.prisma.userVoterAssignment.findMany({
        where: where,
        skip: limit ? skip : undefined,
        take: limit || undefined,
        include: {
          voter: {
            include: {
              belongsToBlock: true,
              pledges: {
                include: {
                  createdByUser: true
                },
                take: 1,
              },
              callMeetups: {
                include: {
                  createdByUser: true,
                }
              },
              createdByUser: true,
              requests: {
                include: {
                  createdByUser: true,
                }
              },
              assignedToUsers: {
                include: {
                  user: true,
                },
                where: {
                  isActive: true,
                }
              },
            },
          },
        },
        orderBy: [
          { createdAt: 'desc'},
          { voter: {
            sumaaruNo: 'asc',
          },},
        ],
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
const {
            _max: { id: maxId },
        } = await this.Prisma.tableName.aggregate({
            _max: { id: true },
        });
```

check the Prisma website to see how to use it following you're requirements

https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-client-reference#aggregate